# Hyperlinks for polygon feature labels - openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I am using Openlayers to display a map and some vector features like polygons and points. Is it possible to have hyperlinks for the label of a vector feature? Does anyone has any idea on how to do this? I have a map which has vector polygons and point features. And the point features could fall within polygon features which makes it hard to click point inside the polygon if both polygon and point features have selectControl. So I am thinking if I can have hyperlinks to the labels of the polygon, I can remove the selectControl for Polygon and do the same functionality by clicking on label instead of anywhere in the polygon.

Thanks,
Aridbh.

Answer (score 1):

One way to add a hyperlink is to put it inside a popup html, I know this is not exactly what you want... perhaps if you make the popup anchored, non-closable and auto-sized you can get closer.